# Calling getOwnerActivity() method always return null

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have created a simple custom dialog class. In further code I want to run new `Intent`:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345"));
           startActivity(intent);
```

But the problem is whenever I call to change into that `Intent` I always get `null` in `getOwnerActivity()` - how to properly call that method?

```
public class AddToQueueDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {

    Activity mActivity;
    private final String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
            Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

    public Activity getmActivity() {
        return mActivity;
    }

    public void setmActivity(Activity mActivity) {
        this.mActivity = mActivity;
    }

    public AddToQueueDialog(Context context, WashLocation washLocation) {
        super(context);
        setWashLocation(washLocation);
        setmActivity(getOwnerActivity());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will check the source code and the activity it returns is set only in setOwnerActivity(Activity activity) which is not called anywhere. So if you want getOwnerActivity() to return value different than null, you have to change your constructor like following

```
 public AddToQueueDialog(Context context, WashLocation washLocation) {
        super(context);
        if (context instanceof Activity) {
             setOwnerActivity((Activity) context);
        }
        setWashLocation(washLocation);
        setmActivity(getOwnerActivity());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant call the getOwnerActivity() in Oncreate

> If you try to get owner from the constructor, Android hasn't hooked it yet, so you have no owner yet.

try this instead

```
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    // getOwnerActivity() should be defined here if called via showDialog(), so do the related init here
    Activity owner = getOwnerActivity();
    if (owner != null) {
        // owner activity defined here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`context` is the owning `Activity`. Your constructor is called with `context`. This is the owning `Activity`.